# Decomposition of an ideal as a product of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

How to show $$5\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}] = (5, \sqrt[3]{2}+2)(5, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2+3\sqrt[3]{2}-1).$$

Firstly, I think that I can say that $$(5, \sqrt[3]{2}+2)(5, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2+3\sqrt[3]{2}-1)= (25,5(\sqrt[3]{2}+2),5((\sqrt[3]{2})^2+3\sqrt[3]{2}-1),5((\sqrt[3]{2})^2+\sqrt[3]{2})).$$ Since 5 divides each term, I have that $(5, \sqrt[3]{2}+2)(5, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2+3\sqrt[3]{2}-1) \subseteq (5)$. But now how do I show the other direction? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working in $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^3-2)$ I get

$$(5,x+2)(5,x^2+3x-1)=\big(25,5(x^2+3x-1),5(x+2),(x+2)(x^2+3x-1)\big).$$

Then $(x+2)(x^2+3x-1)=x^3+5x^2+5x-2=5x(x+1)$. Hence the above ideal is

$$=(5)(5,x^2+3x-1,x+2,x^2+x).$$

Use the Euclidean division algorithm (which applies here) to simplify the right-hand factor. For example $x^2+3x-1\equiv x-1$ mod $x+2$ so we may replace $x^2+3x-1$ with $x-1$.

Comment: It is not clear to me how we are applying the division algorithm. Why are we modding out by $x+2$?

Comment: @Galois Look at the ideal I wrote in the second centered equation. Do you see that $x+2$ there? The rules for the Euclidean algorithm works with ideals, e.g. $(a,b)=(b,a)=(a+b,a)$ etc. and apply just as well when there is more than one generator listed out. (Speaking somewhat geometrically, applying these rules is tantamount to base change but with spanning sets.)

Comment: I see. So the RHS $= (5,x+2, x-1, -x)$ but now what?

Comment: @Galois Continue simplifying! Hint: Since there's already a $(5)$ in front of this ideal, and you know the final result should be $(5)$, you can expect this ideal to simplify to just $(1)$. So... make it happen.

Comment: RHS $= (5,x+2,-1,-x) = (5, 2, -1 ,-x) = (5,1,-1,-x)=(1)$.

Comment: Once you get $1$ you're done. Because $(1,\square,\triangle,\rm tomato,\cdots)=(1)$. Any ideal that contains a unit like $\pm1$ is the whole ring. Furthermore you cannot just throw generators out of an ideal willy-nilly (like you threw out $1$ and $-1$.) We have $(a,b,c,\cdots)=(b,c,\cdots)$ iff $a\in(b,c,\cdots)$.

Answer (score 2):

anon gave you the elementary answer, but if we want to use more machinery, we can use the Dedekind-Kummer theorem.

Namely, to factor $5\mathcal{O}_K$ (where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$) it suffices to factor $x^3-2$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$. But, this factors as $(x+2)(x^2+3x+4)$. Thus, we know that

$$5\mathcal{O}_K=(5,\sqrt[3]{2}+2)(5,\sqrt[3]{2}^2+3\sqrt[3]{2}+4)$$

But, by subtracting $5$ from the second entry in the second ideal gives your factorization.